# Printing/Parsing csv blob file from mysql

Tags: python, mysql, blob

Querying blob files in database, is it possible to read as text from blob files rather than array

Here my simple code:

```
sql= "select blob_file as blob_file from Blob_Table limit 1"                                          
cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()

for i in result :
    print i["file_backup"]
```

My output is something like these, an array.array type:

```
array('b', [67, 97, 114, 114, 105, 101, 114, 32, 73, 68, 44, 83, 116, 97, 103, 101, 32, 82, 111, 119, 44, 83, 116, 97, 103, 101, 32, 67, 111, 108, 117, 109, 110, 44, 68, 97, 116, 101, 44, 84, 105, 109, 101, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 50, 76, 32, 68, 101, 112, 116, 104, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 82, 97, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 68, 101, 112, 116, 104, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 65, 66, 83, 32, 81, 117, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121, 32, 111, 102, 32, 70, 105, 116, 44, 67, 111, 110, 102, 105, 103, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 40, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 111, 110, 108, 121, 41, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 65, 66, 83, 32, 80, 105, 120, 32, 67, 111, 117, 110, 116, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 50, 110, 100, 32, 76, 118, 108, 32, 80, 105, 120, 32, 67, 111, 117, 110, 116, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 80, 105, 120, 32, 67, 111, 117, 110, 116, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 82, 113, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 65, 66, 83, 32, 81, 117, 97, 100, 32, 67, 114, 111, 119, 110, 44, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 32, 70, 105, 116, 32, 81, 117, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121, 44, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 32, 82, 111, 116, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 44, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 32, 88, 32, 84, 114, 97, 110, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 44, 84, 101, 4, 54, 13, 10])
```

Is possible to convert these because my blob file is pure text from csv..

Answer (score 0):

First, the type you have there appears to be a byte array. For the purpose of testing, I run the following to get myself the same byte array as you:

`raw_results = bytearray([67, 97, 114, 114, 105, 101, 114, 32, 73, 68, 44, 83, 116, 97, 103, 101, 32, 82, 111, 119, 44, 83, 116, 97, 103, 101, 32, 67, 111, 108, 117, 109, 110, 44, 68, 97, 116, 101, 44, 84, 105, 109, 101, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 50, 76, 32, 68, 101, 112, 116, 104, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 82, 97, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 68, 101, 112, 116, 104, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 65, 66, 83, 32, 81, 117, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121, 32, 111, 102, 32, 70, 105, 116, 44, 67, 111, 110, 102, 105, 103, 32, 110, 97, 109, 101, 40, 110, 97, 109, 101, 32, 111, 110, 108, 121, 41, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 65, 66, 83, 32, 80, 105, 120, 32, 67, 111, 117, 110, 116, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 50, 110, 100, 32, 76, 118, 108, 32, 80, 105, 120, 32, 67, 111, 117, 110, 116, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 80, 105, 120, 32, 67, 111, 117, 110, 116, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 67, 97, 118, 105, 116, 121, 32, 82, 113, 44, 65, 65, 66, 32, 65, 66, 83, 32, 81, 117, 97, 100, 32, 67, 114, 111, 119, 110, 44, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 32, 70, 105, 116, 32, 81, 117, 97, 108, 105, 116, 121, 44, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 32, 82, 111, 116, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 44, 84, 101, 109, 112, 108, 97, 116, 101, 32, 88, 32, 84, 114, 97, 110, 108, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 44, 84, 101, 4, 54, 13, 10])`

Now I want to get this into an easier to work with format, that is a string:
`results = raw_results.decode('utf-8')`

This should do it.

Going forward you will probably want to use the `csv` module to read your csv string so that you don't have to deal with issues like quoted commas. However, the csv reader typically reads from a file, but it works with anything that iterates over lines. So you probably want to do something like this to actually work with the data. See [Python csv string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305926/python-csv-string-to-array) for an example.