# Split string by comma and escape string

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I'm using python2.7. In my script i receive lines from server in next format:

```
product,"Tom,Jerry\\n",r,0
product,Another Title,r,1
```

So i need read this string line by line. And then read 4 values to list. But i can't simple do `split(",")`, because we can have `,` character in title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) can read lines from a list.

```
>>> import csv
>>> S = """product,"Tom,Jerry\\n",r,0
... product,Another,r,1"""
>>> for row in csv.reader(S.splitlines()):
...     print row
... 
['product', 'Tom,Jerry\\n', 'r', '0']
['product', 'Another', 'r', '1']
```

Comment: thanks, this answer also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305926/python-csv-string-to-array