# Expand regex to check for delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I have string that can be like

- "blahblah...blah"
- "blahblah...blah";12
- -12.4;"blah";"TRUE".

Basically there can be any number or elements in string separated with `";"` (if more then one element) where elements are names enclosed with `"` or numbers.

I have tried to create a pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/DvH8Br/2/), but I don't know how to include check that to know delimiter is `;` character.

For reference string and pattern are:

```
word = '"dadada";-15.7;15;"TRUE"'
p = r'(?:\"\w+\"|[+-]?\d{1,3}\.?\d{1})+'
```

Edit: 
What I would like to do is extract data between `;` if exists and I thought maybe this can be done with regex. Data in not read from csv file.

Comment: Do you want to separate these items? Have a look at e.g. `pandas.read_csv()` with `sep=;`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305926/python-csv-string-to-array

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the regex? You want to split the string by the delimiter ? Write in the question what you are trying to achieve as well. It might be that there are better ways to achieve it than regex.