# Inserting a tuple yielding error: Not enough arguments for format string

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to insert data received through serial into a mysql table using python 3, however, when I try to input my insert statement I get a "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string".  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried using `", (new_data)"` instead of `"% (new_data)"` and got SQL syntax error.  Also tried `".format(new_data)"` which did not produce an error, but resulted in empty string fields or 0.00 float fields.

```
raw_data=ser.readline() #Fetch a line from the serial feed

new_data=raw_data.decode('ascii').rstrip()  #Remove extraneous control characters

new_data=(new_data, ) #Convert to a tuple

#Result
#("'2019-5-21 7:55:5',0,3.1,25.6,315,2.2,316,11.0,248,56.6,56.9,0.00,0.73,100375.50,4.37,0.83",)

#Now insert into the database
sql="INSERT INTO reports (rec_time, wnddir, wndspd, wndgust, wndgustdir, wndspdavg2m, wnddiravg2m, wndgustavg10M, wndgustdiravg10M, humidity, tempf, rain, raindly, pressure, battery, light) VALUES ('%s', '%d', '%f', '%f', '%d', '%f', '%d', '%f', '%d', '%f', '%f', '%f', '%f', '%f', '%f', '%f')" % (new_data)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

I am expecting a record to be written to the database, however, I get a "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string". There are 16 fields, 16 placeholders and 16 pieces of data.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You have an extra `"` inside the `sql` string, before `'%d'`.

Comment: That should be causing a Python syntax error, not a type error. Was it a copy/paste error?

Comment: Yes, it was a copy and paste error.  Sorry.

Comment: `new_data` is a tuple with 1 element in it, the string that was returned by `raw_data.decode('ascii').rstrip()`. Where do the 15 other values come from?

Comment: The quotes and commas inside the string don't cause them to become separate elements of the tuple. It's still just a single string, which you need to parse. It looks like this is a CSV file, perhaps you should use the `csv` module?

Comment: Given that comment, my error would be in creating the tuple from the raw string of data?  I thought I was creating tuple with 16 elements based on comma delimiters.

Comment: No. Variables are never automatically parsed as if the contents are part of the source code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305926/python-csv-string-to-array for how to parse a CSV row from a string.

Comment: Thank you!  I will!

Comment: You should also avoid using string formatting to create SQL. Put placeholders in the string and let `cursor.execute()` substitute them. This prevents SQL-injection.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 16 fields, 16 placeholders and 16 pieces of data.

```
new_data=(new_data, ) #Convert to a tuple
```

No, there's just a 1-tuple, rather than a 16-tuple.

Consider this example:

```
>>> 6,
(6,)
```

It creates a 1-tuple, containing the single element six.
In your case, you created a 1-tuple containing a string,
one which has many characters, including commas.
But it's still a 1-tuple, so `.format()` is still looking for 15 more args.

Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module to iterate over your input file,
and you'll be much happier.